# Better jQuery object filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, filter

Working on a js app involving many objects, I want to be able to grab an object by a specific variable. Here is my code:

```
var pin = '0000';

$.each(employees, function(){
    if(this.pin === pin){
        curEmployee = this;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Though this approach works, I have a feeling that there are way better solutions out there... I was fiddling around with grep and tried:

```
var pin = '0000';

curEmployee = $.grep(employees, function(e,i){
    return e[pin] === pin;
});
```

However, it is harder to determine a result, since now I will need to check the length to see if an array with provided back, and such.

Just looking for a best practices solution.

Comment: This is probably better suited for CodeReview - *best practice* questions will solicit debate, which is good to avoid on SO.

Comment: I use the first one always, because of the "break" that allows enumerating only what's necessary. Maybe it's just an old school habit though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since an Array is always returned from `$.grep`, just get the `[0]` index of the Array. If `undefined`, there was no match.

```
var pin = '0000';

curEmployee = $.grep(employees, function(e,i){
    return e.pin === pin;
})[0]; // <--- always grab the first index
```

Without jQuery, you could use `Array.prototype.filter` in the same manner:

```
var pin = '0000';

curEmployee = employees.filter(function(e,i){
    return e.pin === pin;
})[0];
```

Comment: Good answer, didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use jquery's `filter` method:

```
var pin = '0000';

curEmployee = $(employees).filter(function(e){
  return e.pin === pin;
})[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

In All honesty, IF you are using aloot of objects and performance is important...

.. and you want to avoid the asynchronous bugies in js.. you should go for a pure js. approach.

Something like for loop which god trough all objects. And possibly some result buffering. I know it is a pain in the ass and you probably wont like to do it. but it is the fastest way in most cases.

I personally use such aproach in a js. crm we are making, becouse the jquery way was a no go on 1000+ objects...